# Can Socket.IO clients be setup to not keep NodeJS from exiting?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is it possible to create a Socket.IO client connection that doesn't block the NodeJS process from exiting? By default if a connection is open, then the NodeJS process will stay running, but there are situations where it would be useful for the process not to wait for the connection to close.

I would imagine a similar usage to NodeJS timeouts; Where you can call `unref()` on a Timer to stop it from blocking the process exit.

Comment: Have you check out the built-in childprocess module

Comment: @AvivLo interesting idea, do you mean opening the Socket.IO connection in the child process and then relaying the events from it back to the parent process?

Comment: Yes sir. Exactly.

Comment: @RyanRossiter Can you further explain your use case as your words "here are situations where it would be useful" I think a short-lived script is one use case. But I can't think of other use case.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

As of version 4, this is now possible! One needs only to pass the `autoUnref` option and then sockets that are open will not keep the NodeJS process running.

Code example:

```js
const socket = io({
  autoUnref: true
});
```

Documentation:

https://socket.io/docs/v4/migrating-from-3-x-to-4-0/#autounref-option

Thanks also to @Gajus for adding a code snippet when I forgot to! Just updating this for consistency.

---

**old answer**

The answer seems to be: no.

So I opened a couple of PR's to add this feature :)

https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client/pull/652

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/pull/1442

If they get accepted I'll update this with example usage.

Comment: Hi I saw autoUnref was added to 4.0 but I was bit confused with its usage because even in 2.x if I close all active socket connections the process will exit. So what does  its usage ?

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 you're right that closing connections allows the process to exit. `autoUnref` makes it so that you don't have to close them explicitly. If they would be the only thing keeping the process alive, node closes them because they have been "unref"d.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am still confused. Does that mean even if the connection is active, the process still will exit? Isn't that wrong?

Comment: With a language like NodeJS, the event loop is everything! It's a common API feature to allow the event loop to exit if some process or another is the only thing left. Consider the timers API: https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/timers/#unref

Now whether you want that behavior in your app is another question, hence it being optional :). If your question is on *that* point, this conversation should be moved to chat or a new question on SO. Cheers!

Comment: I had found your pull request and commented on it https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client/pull/652

Answer (score 1):

```
const socket = io({
  autoUnref: true
});
```

https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-3-x-to-4-0/#autounref-option